# NSMutableArray check object at specific index

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have got an NSMutableArray before adding values to which I check if it's already there and I put this value at index 0.
However, if the value is already there, I would like to know it's there at the specific index.
This code doesn't work:

```
if ([theQueueArray containsObject:elementName atIndex:0])
```

How do you do it right, then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking if an array "contains" an item at a specific index just sounds like a fancy way of stating the general case of accessing any item from an array at a given index, no?

```
if ([[theQueueArray objectAtIndex:0] isEqual:elementName]) {
    // ...
}
```

(If this isn't what you mean, consider clarifying the question.)

Comment: This approach helped me. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

`(NSUInteger)indexOfObject:(id)anObject` ?
Return Value: The lowest index whose corresponding array value is equal to anObject. If none of the objects in the array is equal to anObject, returns NSNotFound.

Answer (score 1):

You can't query by element name.  You'd need a copy of the object your looking for to check like this.  You'd need something more like:

```
if([[theQueryArray objectAtIndex:0] compare: @"elementName"] == NSOrderedSame)
```

Comment: But the code `if ([theQueueArray containsObject:elementName])` works just fine for me

Answer (score 0):

[searchArray containsObject:elementName] you can use it